# Dynamically enable/disable panning on QML map

Tags: qml

I need to disable and enable panning on my QML map dynamically.
In more detail, I need with the press of a button to be able to suppress panning and then to do the opposite with another button. 
I had a look online but I cannot find anything that helps or at least I did not spot it. There is documentation on how to do it for touch gestures but not for when using a normal monitor and a mouse.

Is there a way to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you referring to some specific QML component when you say "QML map"?

Comment: I am refering to Map QML type http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtlocation-map.html

Comment: It sounds more like a hack, but you could put a `MouseArea` over the map, set `preventStealing: true` in the `MapGestureArea` and steal any mouse input from there.

Comment: Why not just disabling the gesture? `Map { gesture.enable: false }`

Comment: I actually used gestures in order to solve my problem, but since I wanted to have the zoom gesture to work while panning to be disabled, I had to dynamically just change the gestures accepted rather than disabling them all. I initially did not try gestures because I thought they were only for finger gestures to be used on a touchscreen and not for mouse input as well. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Very well. If you solved your issue please consider to answer the queston with the solution you have found.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtlocation-mapgesturearea.html#acceptedGestures-prop) you can use `gesture.acceptedGestures`  and accept everything but `MapGestureArea.PanGesture`.
Here is an example how you can turn on and off the panning:

```
Window {
    width: 512
    height: 512
    visible: true

    property bool disable_panning : false
    property int no_panning : (MapGestureArea.PinchGesture | MapGestureArea.FlickGesture |MapGestureArea.RotationGesture | MapGestureArea.TiltGesture)
    property int panning : (MapGestureArea.PanGesture | MapGestureArea.PinchGesture | MapGestureArea.FlickGesture |MapGestureArea.RotationGesture | MapGestureArea.TiltGesture)
    Map
    {
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: Plugin{ name: "osm"}

        gesture.acceptedGestures: disable_panning ? no_panning : panning

        RowLayout
        {
            Button
            {
                text: "Disable panning"
                onClicked: {
                    disable_panning = true
                }
            }
            Button
            {
                text: "Enable panning"
                onClicked: {
                    disable_panning = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```